# I am trying to run a hello world function and it gives me an error

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

My IDE is Eclipse IDE 2020.03, using a directory for Minecraft mods made with gradlew setDecompWorkspace and gradlew eclipse

i already tried changing the -vm directory to jdk 1.8.0 and jre/bin/javaw.exe

the error says : Error : Could not create Java Virtual Machine. Error : A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

the code and eclipse.ini looks like this :

```
code :

package com.comteul09.tutorialmod;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}

eclipse.ini :

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\herbw\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\herbw\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.15.0.20200313-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error - could not create java virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the -vm argument might look on Windows (your exact path to javaw.exe could be different, of course. Please beware of paths that contain a space, the examples below do not have any spaces, and using quotation marks around paths that contain spaces does not seem to work):

```
-vm
C:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
```

Or

```
-vm
C:\progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\javaw.exe
```

An alternative way is to insert the following VM option before the -vmargs option in the Eclipse shortcut's properties (edit the field Target inside the "Shortcut" tab):

```
-vm C:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
```

or

```
-vm C:\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\java.exe
```

This might not work on all systems. If you encounter "Java was started but returned exit code=1" error while starting the eclipse, modify the -vm argument to point to jvm.dll (exact path could be different):

```
-vm
C:\Development\Java\64bit\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Reference: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

`--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` is not a valid VM argument before Java 9. Remove that line, and make sure your Java Application's launch configuration does not have it as a VM argument if you're launching your application with Java 8, too.

Comment: how do I change the application's launch config

Comment: Go to the Run menu and select Run...Configurations

Comment: and then what do I do?

Comment: Make sure the VM argument isn't set where you set those. https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-executionArgs.htm?cp=1_3_6_6